# Split Each Line in TextFile By comma and insert each split to lists(2)

Tags: python

im new to python and im looking for way to split text file output for 2 arrays and add them to ordered arrays

my text file looks like this

```
635992586,3718353429462250608
512101346,-5360506753539257325
464545614,2956310376478608644
448112867,-8362724325646859899
610706243,-3741068853182057127
583963913,-8936195924352638585
718532836,1783727609775441510
629842082,7499962062290955876
474659002,6480312120027362804
674787762,-3939702333232947477
457685296,-728255804367320714
445202854,-308676821356105829
762185989,-450762068712661096
345639374,6008304336530590920
561355579,-9018640421044127624
642304902,-3543147906925834368
493117557,2869749777644350319
393747681,812127138086916717
659310463,8747373126642898620
645009089,2643962417775803568
457146237,-5936132366977615159
725713836,-1906036700187282129
573896405,1703425138937300221
```

my goal is to create 2 arrays , and split it by this method
arr 1 takes the long fields(as string) that found in the right side of the list

and arr2 take the ints as string thats found left to the list

examp =

```
arr1[0] = 5360506753539257325
arr2[0] = 512101346
```

and keep until the end of the text file

string myArray[100];
int array_count = 0;

```
ifstream file((path+dicfile).c_str());
std::string line;

while (std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(iss, str, ','))
    {
        myArray[array_count] = str; // value to array
        cout << str << "\n";
        strings.push_back(str);
        array_count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Er, this is tagged Python...

Comment: This definitely appears to be C++ and not python. Specifically C++ because of the use of string.c_str() http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/ and std::

Comment: Putting this on hold pending clarification of whether you want to do this in C++ or Python. Please [edit] your question and clarify. Make sure to update the tags.

Comment: @CodyGray: From the first sentence "im new to python", it seems clear enough to me...

Comment: @martineau Did you miss the C++ code at the bottom of the question? How do you square that with your interpretation? Either way, guessing is not productive. If Wellzar wants an answer, we'll be happy to help, as soon as they clarify exactly what they want.

Comment: @Cody: No, didn't miss the C++ code...but think about it, why else would the question be tagged "python" and the OP say they were new to the language?

Answer (score 1):

You can open and read text files as a csv file with the `csv` module that comes standard with python:

```
import csv

list1 = []
list2 = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    my_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in my_reader:
        list1.append(row[0])
        list2.append(row[1])

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Output:

List1

> ['635992586', '512101346', '464545614', '448112867', '610706243', '583963913', '718532836', '629842082', '474659002', '674787762', '457685296', '445202854', '762185989', '345639374', '561355579', '642304902', '493117557', '393747681', '659310463', '645009089', '457146237', '725713836', '573896405']

List2

> ['3718353429462250608', '-5360506753539257325', '2956310376478608644', '-8362724325646859899', '-3741068853182057127', '-8936195924352638585', '1783727609775441510', '7499962062290955876', '6480312120027362804', '-3939702333232947477', '-728255804367320714', '-308676821356105829', '-450762068712661096', '6008304336530590920', '-9018640421044127624', '-3543147906925834368', '2869749777644350319', '812127138086916717', '8747373126642898620', '2643962417775803568', '-5936132366977615159', '-1906036700187282129', '1703425138937300221']

I think this accomplishes what you were asking, but this is in python (like you tagged) yet your example code is **not** in python...